# Odd behavior when updating interface as part of willActivate

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I have a `WKInterfaceController` subclass that shows a 6 row `WKInterfaceTable`.  This class is also initial interface controller.  When receiving a notification action via `handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification` I am modally presenting a second interface controller.  The user takes no action on the modally presented interface controller, but loading it modifies the state of one of the 6 objects used by the row controllers in the initial interface. When the modal controller is dismissed, my intent is to reflect the updated state in the table.

I have no issues retrieving the updated objects since their management is handled by another class that I can simply query for updated data. Since the initial interface controller has already executed `awakeWithContext:`, I can only rely on `willActivate` to updating the interface.  This seems to be in line with Apple's guidelines since I'm not initializing the interface as part of that method, merely updating it.

TL;DR;

When I update the rows via the row controller, only the value that was updated is displayed properly on the cells.  The other cells use the default values assigned to the labels in my cell at design time on the storyboard.

For example

- Row 1:  Count - 3 Best - 3
- Row 2:  Count - 42 Best - 99
- Row 3:  Count - 42 Best - 99

The extremely curious part is that this only happens on subsequent calls to `willActivate`.  When just opening the watch app and updating the interface for the first time in `willActivate` it behaves as expected.  When being activated as a result of the modal dismissing, this behavior creeps up.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: With only 6 rows, is it reasonable to try and reload the entire table instead of updating just the one?  Does that solve the issue?

Comment: I am reloading the entire table, it's just that only one of the rows should change, because only one of the underlying value objects has been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible issues.

First, the WatchKit interface controllers behave as though they are snapshotted in page sets. After they have been displayed once, the values won't update after being deactivated until they are fully on screen and your `willActivate` method has been called. Switching images has the same as switching a table row label when the interface isn't visible. It MUST be done in `willActivate` otherwise it appears to get dropped.

The other problem I've seen related to this is when you `setNumberOfRows`, you need to update the values in ALL rows. Otherwise you will end up with customized row values for the ones you set, and the default values from the storyboard for all other rows. If you're only updating the values for a particular row in willActivate and not calling the `setNumberOfRows` on the Table, then I'd say you should file a bug with Apple's [Bug Reporting System](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: yeah that's what I'm realizing, it seems like unless the value changes between calls, it's loading the default.  I think there was already a bug filed on this that I found after posting this.

Comment: Cool, it's always a great idea to file a duplicate bug report to continue to up the priority. If the answer is sufficient, it would be awesome if you would mark it as such.